# filter non blank cells for pivot table created with data model vba

Tags: excel, vba, olap, olap-cube

I have created  a OLAP pivot table with data model as need to used distinct count function.  It has a field named "AOM", which is in Row field and having some blank values. Expectation to get the pivot data for non blank cells only.
Below is the macro which I have created. It is running fine without any error however nothing is happening means blanks cells are not getting filtered out..

```
Sub ShowVisbilityOfNonBlankItem()

On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").pivotFields("AOM")
.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the field "AOM" or "AOM Name" ?

Comment: field name is "AOM"

Comment: What is the result if you remove the On Error Resume Next ?